# Ubuntu 13.10 Mouse Scroll Wheel does in work in GTK3 apps

Tags: 13.10, mouse-wheel

Scrolling is ok with a mouse in Firefox, but not with GTK3 apps. With the touch pad, two fingers scrolling works with all apps.

I tested with xev and get button 4 and 5

Answer (score 7):

Here is a bug notice for this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1200829

There is a ppa with patched GTK code that fixes the issue

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/test-scroll

I can confirm the ppa code fixes the scroll wheel issue

Comment: On my Ubuntu 13.10, I can scroll with mouse wheel in GTK3 apps when using Unity or Gnome 3, but not when using Xfce (xubuntu-desktop). So this bug cannot be only Compiz-related, as the Xfce desktop does not use Compiz.

Comment: Anyway, installing the packages from that PPA, fixed the scrolling in GTK3 apps in Xfce. So thank you!