# Mouse-scroll does not work in gedit

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, gedit, gtk3

Since the update to 13.10 scrolling in Gedit does not work anymore. Anywhere else it does.

It could be related with [Bug #1240957 “Scrolling behaviour and window focus has changed a...” : Bugs : “gtk+3.0” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1240957) but I need scrolling. Updating to the latest gtk3.0 available in proposed/unsupported did not help. Does anybody have the same problem? How i can solve this problem

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Couldn't find anything elsewhere. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.10 Mouse Scroll Wheel does in work in GTK3 apps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356640/ubuntu-13-10-mouse-scroll-wheel-does-in-work-in-gtk3-apps)

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1200829)

There is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/test-scroll) with patched GTK code that fixes the issue

Comment: "ppa" link goes to a missing page. Where is the fix?